# WPF vb.net Make buttons on Window enable after click event on Page

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, events, click

I have a `Window` and a `Page`. The `Window` has 3 buttons, which are disable by default. The `Page` has 1 button that when clicked 10 times shows a message, and should enable the buttons on the `Window`.

How would I enabled the 3 buttons in the Window AFTER the button in the `Page` is clicked 10 times?

MainWindow XAML:

```
 <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="Window1Grid">
        <Grid x:Name="FrameGrid">
            <Button IsEnabled="False" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,56,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
            <Button IsEnabled="False" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,112,0,0" Name="Button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
            <Button IsEnabled="False" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,165,0,0" Name="Button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        </Grid>
        <Frame Source="Page1.xaml" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,38,0,0" Name="Frame1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow .vb

```
   Public Class MainWindow

End Class
```

Page1 .Xaml

```
<Page x:Class="Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="Page1">
<Grid x:Name="Page1Grid" Background="Red">
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,166,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,12,0,0" Name="Page1TxtBlock" Text="Page1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Page 1 .vb

```
Class Page1
Dim clicks As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try


        clicks += 1

        If clicks >= 10 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Window Buttons should be enabled")
            clicks = 0

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML. Also you may want to use `Window.ShowDialog()` instead.

Comment: That would not work because the child (page) is through a frame.

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML. your explanation does not explain the situation well. You start your question by saying `I have a parent window and a child window`, but now you tell me that it's not a child window, but a Page, which is a completely different thing.

Comment: Sorry. Updated content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT as asked in the comment

On click on parent button disable all three buttons

in your Page1 class:

`Dim parentWindow as MainWindow;`

then overload Page constructor:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal mw As MainWindow)
    parentWindow=mw
End Sub
```

when initializing Page in Frame use

```
Dim p As New Page1(Me)
frame.Content = p
```

call it from page1 using

```
parentWindow.btnSomethinf.IsEnabled=true...
```

Comment: I translated this into VB(sorry) it looks like this will work. However when I put ParentWindow.btn1.IsEnabled (which is MainWindow.Button1.IsEnabled) in Page 1 button even I get" Reference to non shared member..."  I am a total newbie. Where would I put the Overload Page constructor? my Page is named Page1 and ParentWindow is named MainWindow. Thanks.

Comment: Overload the Page constructor would be like this:  Public Sub Page1(ByVal MainWindow) End Sub correct?

Comment: How would I do this if MainWindow had frame1 which showed page1 and page 1 had pageframe1 which showed page 2(frame within frame) . How would page2 enable buttons in MainWindow? Possible?

Comment: Just overload the page2 constructor the same way and call it `Dim p2 As New Page2(parentwindow)`

Comment: "I am getting a XAMLParseExeption was unhandled"error: 'No matching constructor found on type 'Test2App.Page2'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.' Line number '5' and line position '7'

Comment: VB code page2: Class Page2
    Dim parentWindow2 As MainWindow
    Public Sub New(ByVal mw2 As MainWindow)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        parentWindow2 = mw2

    End Sub
End Class

Comment: VB code page1: Class Page1
    Dim parentWindow As MainWindow
    Public Sub New(ByVal mw As MainWindow)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        parentWindow = mw
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
       
    End Sub

End Class

Comment: VB Code MainWindow:Public Class MainWindow
    Dim parentWindow2 As MainWindow
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim p As New Page1(Me)
        Frame1.Content = p

        Dim p2 As New Page2(Me)
        Frame1.Content = p2
    End Sub


End Class  Hmmm Any clue where the error is coming from? Thanks.

Comment: can you upload the project somewhere so I can look into the actual code?